# My iCloud and phone storage is full and my camera permissions in all apps have been turned off and disabled. Please suggest how to resolve this?

Tags: icloud, video, storage, youtube

My iPhone storage is full and iCloud as well. I tried to delete some pictures and videos and apps.  But it seems like they are not deleting and nothing is changing on my phone. I have tried uploading videos to YouTube so I can delete them from my phone. I did that for a few days. Now all of my apps cannot access the camera through Settings at all or request permission through Settings or privacy. I need help. I have iOS 13.6. I also have another software update pending but I do not have enough storage to download it.

Comment: Can you buy more iCloud space for a month?

Comment: I can’t. I have the largest storage plan for iCloud already which is 2TB.

Comment: Do you have a Mac?

Comment: You should look into DropBox or Box and see if you can get more storage.

Comment: Yes I have a MacBook Air! Ok I will look into Dropbox and see if it works.

Comment: Have you used Dropbox or Box before?

Comment: I use Dropbox and Box both.  They have free accounts that consist of 2 GB I think and then you can buy much more but it's not a cheap as Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has an article walking through how to rescue a device that needs space to get to 13.6.1.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211686

Worst case, back up to a computer and then use that to get you past the space crunch. I’m delighted with how 13.6.1 has helped me use space better on iOS.